# FIND_IN_SET example for string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using FIND_IN_SET and getting following error

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function find_in_set(unknown, character varying[]) does not exist   
>   Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

I have used the following example

```
where FIND_IN_SET ('US', country_codes) and  
where FIND_IN_SET ('"US"', country_codes)
```

Table is as following

```
COUNTRY_CODES
{US, CA}
{US, CA, UT}
{FR, BG, ET}

    and want to use for group by country_codes where as it should consider     COUNTRY_CODES
        {US, CA}
        {US, CA, UT} as same country as it is coming in the query
where as group by consider it as different country
```

Comment: where is the `country_codes` variable defined ?

Comment: Where [in the Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index.html) did you find `find_in_set()`?

Answer (score 2):

This error output seriously looks like you are running Postgres, *not* MySQL.

If the `country_codes` column is actually a Postgres array, then just use this:

```
WHERE country_codes @> ARRAY['US']::varchar[]
```

If you really are storing CSV data in a string column, then I suggest using the following logic instead:

```
WHERE ',' || country_codes || ',' LIKE '%,US,%'
```

To see what the above logic is doing, consider that you are trying to match the following CSV list of country codes:

```
US,CA,UT
```

which becomes

```
,US,CA,UT,
```

Then, it is clear that `,US,` is present in that CSV string.  Note that you should avoid storing CSV data directly in your SQL tables.

Comment: Since this is _varchar: Character string array type content, So like is not available for that. Like works for plain string

Comment: I gave you an option at the end of my answer for handling an array.  Your suggestion that the content is CSV also might have been the case, before your above comment.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.